# Wordpress hardcode <!--nextpage--> in php

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

In Wordpress we can split a post with `<!--nextpage-->`, if we put it in the code version of the post-editor. This is working for me. BUT what is, if I want to hardcode this in the themes loop file? How can I get this to work?

Assume I have something like this in my loop file:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages(foobarbaz); ?>
```

Obviously the following solution won't work:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<!--nextpage-->
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages(foobarbaz); ?>
```

I have no clue where I could find the right php function that is executed when `<!--nextpage-->` gets parsed in the code editor.
The only solution I can think of is creating a new post with just `<!--nextpage-->` in it and somehow try to hardcode this specific post inside the loop file. But there has to be a much better and cleaner way of doing it...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do but you can control the number of posts that appear on an archive page on the Settings->Reading tab.

If you want to split your content in individual posts, I think the best way to do this is to hook into the 'the_content' filter. I'm not sure if you have criteria where you want to split the post but if it's word count and you don't want to use `the_excerpt;`, you can write a function (in your theme's functions.php file) like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'your_post_split');
function your_post_split($content) {
//do something with the content and insert <!--nextpage--> 
return $content;
}
```

When you write filters, make sure you always return the variable coming into your function.

If you want to prepend your post with the excerpt text, try this:

```
function your_post_split($content) {
 global $post;
 $content = $post->post_excerpt . $content;
 return $content;
}
```

Take `<?php the_excerpt; ?>` out of your template.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried your code but got an error. I modified it to `add_filter('the_content', 'your_post_split');
function your_post_split($content) {
return "<!--nextpage-->" . $content;
}`. This works but it just shows <!--nextpage--> before the post_content. It is not getting executed and I need the code to get executed...

Comment: What is not getting executed? `<!--nextpage-->` is not code. It's just a server side string that WordPress uses to end the content output and add a link to the rest of the content. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes you are right. What I was trying to do is separating `the_excerpt` from `the_content`. (Both are in the same post, I know this is strange, don't ask why, but in this project it makes sense to use this unorthodox method...) When a user clicks on a post, he sees the excerpt followed by the content. I wanted to split the two in the same post, but it seems far more complicated than I initially thought, because this also affects `the_excerpt`, resulting in an empty excerpt. The code above is doing the following: "excerpt of post" `<!--nextpage-->` "content of post" instead of splitting the two.

Comment: Might not be that hard because you can hook into a couple of filters but I don't understand what you mean by "splitting the two."

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to achieve: Lets assume this is one single post with excerpt and content: abcdefg... abcdefghijklmn. I would like to have the same post look like this: abcdefg... "click here to see full post" (=simple pagination to page 2) --> after click on the link: abcdefghijklmn. So the question is, how can I make abcdefg... (=excerpt) page 1 and abcdefghijklmn (=content) page 2. I need to hardcode the solution because I need to update about 100.000 posts like this. I hope I expressed myself clear enough, if not please ask and thank you for your repeated help on this.

Comment: If I understand properly, you want to show the excerpt on page load and then hide it and reveal the content on a click. This is a job for javascript and jQuery rather than php, in my opinion. You can filter the_content to (1) wrap the excerpt with a div tag, (2) append that html string with an a tag to give your reader something to link to, (3) wrap the_content in a div tag with a style="display:none" attribute. In your jQuery function, you would assign the click on the a tag to hide the_excerpt div and show the_content div. This wouldn't require a page refresh either.

Comment: You are absolutely right that a convenient way to solve this involves using javascript. Thanks for pointing it out. But doing it this way I have little control over what the search engines exactly see on a given post, what I want them to index and so on. Another way to solve my problem would be a script that can automatically produce an excerpt in a new post with a link to the full content post. That would double the amount of posts, yes, but it would be better than nothing. If I could hardcode a solution in php, this would be the most effective way and gives me full control over the site.

Comment: As a reader, having to click to read full content with a page refresh would not be a good experience. I'm also not sure how WordPress would handle the permalinks for your "split" posts. I generally don't do much with SEO so if that's an issue, I'll leave that to others. Good luck.